# 2.8 Toggle the display of objects as a box of their extents?

Tags: 3d-view

I find old answers to this. I can go to Object Properties->Display As->Bounds. But you can only do it per object. So you can't select all 100 objects lets say, to view as their extents in a box wireframe format. You would have to do them one at a time. And even if you could select all 100 or so, going back and forth would be tedious.

3D studio has a hot key to switch the viewport into this mode so that all objects suddenly show their orientation as simple see-thru boxes. Either way, when lining up the edges of irregular shapes, it helps to display them constrained to an outline resembling a box (be it oblong/rectangular/etc).

Surely there is an easier way?
Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

To change the same attribute on multiple objects at the same time:

1. Select all objects
2. Hover your mouse-pointer over the attribute you want to change
3. Hold <kbd>Alt</kbd> and either enter the new value by selecting from a list like this:
   [image]
   *(shown here is the UI of Blender 2.90, but it works the same in older versions.)*
4. Or in other cases with values, click in the field and enter a new value.

After the list was opened with <kbd>Alt</kbd> held, or a value selected also while <kbd>Alt</kbd> was held, the attribute will be changed for all currently selected objects. This will though not work if you have different types of objects selected that do not share the attribute you want to change, like a few Cubes and a Light for example.

Happy Blending

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you so very much. I expect the ALT key may work with other things as well.